# Is it possible to rename an entire “directory of branches”?

Tags: git, git-branch

Git branches can have path-like names, such as `f2003-conv/f90ppr-tool/debug_issueX`. Is it possible to actually use these as directories, as in, rename `f2003-conv/f90ppr-tool` with all its sub-branches?

Answer (score 1):

Since branch names are arbitrary, I don't think Git has any built-in way to do this, but here's a little script, [credit to edenwaith](https://gist.github.com/edenwaith/3eb5c41c5a7d68449ec9).

```
git branch \
| grep f2003-conv/f90ppr-tool \
| awk '{original=$1; sub("f2003-conv/f90ppr-tool","simpler-path"); print original, $1}' \
| xargs -n 2 git branch -m
```